# How to pass nodes to BalkanOrgchart js and how to apply colours for each node?

Tags: orgchart

I have created nodes data as json format. But, I need to pass nodes data to BalkanOrgchart by ajax. But, there is no document related to this. And, i have set colours for each node. I mean different colours. But, it is not reflected on PDF export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add css on export, set extrahtml option

Here is an example:

js

```
menu: {
    exportPdf: {
        text: 'Export PDF',
        icon: OrgChart.icon.pdf(24,24),
        onClick: function(){chart.exportPDF({
            extraHtml: document.getElementById('myStyles').outerHTML
        })}
    }
},
```

css

```
<style id="myStyles">
    .node{
        font-family: Helvetica;
    }
    .node.QA rect {
        fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .node.QA text {
        fill: #F57C00;
    }


    .node.Marketing rect {
        fill:#ffffff;
    }

    .node.Marketing text {
        fill: #FFCA28;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I have one question, Possible to add your "balkanorgchart-js" to Angular cli 6? you have any npm file?